# Overflow-safe way to calculate percentage from two longs in Java

Tags: java

I have two non-negative longs. They may be large, close to Long.MAX_VALUE. I want to calculate a percentage from the two numbers.

Usually I'd do this:

```
    long numerator = Long.MAX_VALUE / 3 * 2;
    long denominator = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    int percentage = (int) (numerator * 100 / denominator);
    System.out.println("percentage = " + percentage);
```

This is not correct if numerator is within two order of magnitudes to Long.MAX_VALUE.

What's a correct, simple, and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd use:

```
int percentage = (int)(numerator * 100.0 / denominator + 0.5);
```

The `100.0` forces floating-point math from that point on, and the `+ 0.5` rounds to the nearest integer instead of truncating.

Comment: Why the ' + 0.5' at the end? I guess it is to give better rounding...but 99.6 would then be 100 which is maybe not so good

Comment: @SteveMcLeod: Yes, it's to do with rounding (see the updated answer). I think rounding to the nearest is a sensible default.

Comment: @SteveMcLeod: Of course, if the use case dictates truncation instead of rounding to the nearest, it is safe to drop the `+0.5`.

Answer (score 7):

```
int percentage = (int) (0.5d + ((double)numerator/(double)denominator) * 100);
```

If you divide a `long` with a `long` you will get a `long`, that is not good for percentages.

Answer (score 4):

Guys implement in following way because it is suggested to do calculations with BigDecimal and BigInteger. Here is implementation:

```
    BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    BigDecimal i = new BigDecimal(100);
    int percentage = n.multiply(i).divide(d).intValue();
    System.out.println(percentage);
```

Answer (score 2):

The trivial way is to convert both to `float` or `double` before doing the calculation, at the expense of a slight loss in precision.  It's also slow, in comparison to alternatives.

One alternative is to split each value into two 32-bit components, and do long-multiplication and long-division.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something obvious can't you just write:

```
public class round {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    long numerator = Long.MAX_VALUE / 3 * 2;
    long denominator = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    int percentage = (int) (numerator / (denominator / 100));
    System.out.println("percentage = " + percentage);

  }
}
```

instead? I.e. Instead of making the numerator bigger before division make the denominator smaller. Since you know the denominator is large there's no risk that the division will give 0, which is the reason for usually writing `(n * 100) / d` when you're not using floating point numbers.

Comment: @SteveMcLeod - I think it's correct for the case where you have integers and know they're large. The usual way of writing is designed to cope with cases where they're small.